# How to count the number of time sum is = 7?

Tags: java

I have to make program to roll 2 dice 100 times, and count the # of time the sum equals 7.

I tried doing a count for loop to count the sums = 7, but think I'm getting off base somewhere in the logic of that.

```
 //    int i = 0;       No. of rolls
 //    int count = 0;   No. of rolls = to 7

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        int dice1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(7);
        int dice2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(7);
        int sum = (dice1 + dice2);
        System.out.println(dice1 + ", " + dice2 + ", total: " + sum + " roll: " + i);
    }

    for (int count = 0; count++) {
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of time sum equaled 7 was " + count);
```

I'm getting the random rolls, roll count, and sum of dice correctly, Just need to figure out how to add a sum = 7 count and I'm getting stuck.

Comment: `if (sum == 7) count++;`?

Comment: Also, your dice values are wrong. They will contain zeroes as `nextInt(7)` will return values from 0-6.

Comment: Add if (sum == 7) { count++; } into your first for loop and delete the other loop?

Comment: Your dice values will be in range 0-6 inclusive. I believe you don't want it to be possible to roll 0s. To fix that use `.nextInt(6) + 1` when assigning values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer using streams

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
      Random rng = new Random();
      long result = IntStream
          .generate(() -> rng.nextInt(6) + rng.nextInt(6) + 2)
          .limit(100)
          .filter(x -> x == 7)
          .count();
      System.out.println("Total number of time sum equaled 7 was " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `for (int count = 0; count++) { ... }` with `if (sum==7) count++` and put it after `int sum = (dice1 + dice2);`

This increases count if the sum is 7 within the loop of your 100 double dice rolls.

To remove the wrong dice range (0-7, see comment @Robby Cornelissen) just do a `randomGenerator.nextInt(6)+1`.

```
    int count = 0; //  No. of rolls = to 7

    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
        int dice1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6)+1;
        int dice2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(6)+1;
        int sum = (dice1 + dice2);
        if (sum==7) count++;
        System.out.println(dice1 + ", " + dice2 + ", total: " + sum + " roll: " + i);
    }

    System.out.println("Total number of time sum equaled 7 was " + count);
```

Comment: I knew I was overthinking this, and this works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course you could boil down those first 4 rows in the loop to `if (randomGenerator.nextInt(6) + randomGenerator.nextInt(6) == 6)  count++;` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, program would look like this :

```
public class Dice
{
    static int count = 0;
    static Random ran = new Random();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100). // iterates 1 to 100
            parallel().// converts to parallel stream
            forEach(i -> {
                rollDiceAndCheckIfSumIs7();
            });// prints to the console
        System.out.println("Out of 100 times, total number of times, sum was 7 is :" + count);

    }

    private static void rollDiceAndCheckIfSumIs7()
    {
        int dice1 = ran.nextInt(7);
        int dice2 = ran.nextInt(7);
        count += (dice1 + dice2 == 7) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Considering this is most likely homework I guess this answer wouldn’t be allowed and you also have a bug in it. Is it really a good idea to create a new Random object each time?

Comment: I consider using a static `int` from inside an parallel stream as anti-pattern.

Comment: @GyroGearless I missed that one.

Comment: I agree, random need to be initialized once.